# React Router Link: Change single param

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have routes as follows:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path={'/'} component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={MapContainer} />
        <Route path={'/about'} component={About} />
        <Route path={'/resources'} component={Resources} />
        <Route path={'/:year'} component={MapContainer} />
        <Route path={'/:year/:region'} component={MapContainer} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

After `/:year` and `/:year/:region`, the list of routes will grow significantly (e.g., `/:year/:region/:country`).

I have a link to change years, but I only want to change the `year` parameter so that a link on the `/2013/northern-africa/morocco` can link to `/2006/northern-africa/morocco`. Essentially, I want it to maintain all the parameters after `year`.

I have this:

```
const years = ['2013', '2006', '2002', '1998', '1995'];
const yearLinks = years.map(y => (<li className={y === this.props.params.year ? 'current' : null}>
  <Link to={`/${y}/${this.props.params.region}`}>{y}</Link>
</li>));
```

This is essentially filling up

```
<ul>
  {yearLinks}
</ul>
```

This only works for region, and I don't want to do something like `for param, value in this.props.params`, and then just append all the params. Seems like `react-router` should be able to handle that. Also, the order of the params won't likely come back in the order that I'll need them to make a valid URL.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a [JsFiddle that demonstrates changing a single parameter](https://jsfiddle.net/vofktn1k/). It uses the [Navigation router](http://grahammendick.github.io/navigation/) instead of the React Router but I hope you're open to that. You can see that you build Hyperlinks using the router's `RefreshLink` component. This has a `includeCurrentData` property that, when set to true, keeps the current URL data. So, to keep the region parameter but change the year, you pass the new year and set `includeCurrentData` to true. If there was a country parameter in the URL it would keep that too. If you've got any questions about the code, please let me know.

```
var {StateNavigator} = Navigation; 
var {RefreshLink} = NavigationReact; 

var Map = ({year, region, stateNavigator}) => {
  var regions = ['northern-africa', 'southern-africa'];
  var years = [2013, 2006, 2002, 1998, 1995];
  return (
    <div>
      {regions.map((region) => 
        <RefreshLink
            navigationData={{region: region}}
            includeCurrentData={true}
            stateNavigator={stateNavigator}>
            {region}
        </RefreshLink>
      )}
      <br/>
      {years.map((year) => 
        <RefreshLink
            navigationData={{year: year}}
            includeCurrentData={true}
            stateNavigator={stateNavigator}>
            {year}
        </RefreshLink>
      )}
      <div>year: {year}</div>
      <div>region: {region}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

var stateNavigator = new StateNavigator([
  {key:'map', route:'{year?}/{region?}', defaults: {year: 2016 }}
]);

stateNavigator.states.map.navigated = (data) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Map year={data.year} region={data.region} stateNavigator={stateNavigator} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
  );
}

stateNavigator.start();
```

Comment: Definitely upvoted due to thoroughness, but I've got `react-router` pretty tightly coupled to `redux` and whatnot. Rewriting this to use your router (great job writing a flexible enough router that that would even be possible!) would make me have to rewrite a bunch of other stuff.